# How to find available memory on a google app engine flex instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, memory

I tested with different instance class options and checked the available memory with the free -h command via SSH, the available memory doesn't change, it gives me the same 988Mi available.

Is there another way to check the available memory or why is it not giving me more memory when I change the instance class?

This is my configuration file:

```
entrypoint: bundle exec rails server -p 8080
env: flex
runtime: ruby
instance_class: B4_1G
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag `instance_class` should be only available for Google App Engine Standard deployments, as stated in the [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#instance_class) reference, but it is not mentioned in the Flexible app.yaml reference.

This is an issue reported to Google [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/127785511), but it seems is not fixed yet. According to this, when that tag is used a default machine with 1GB is created. Which matches your situation.

The correct way to assign resources in Flexible is by using the tag `resources`. See the [reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings) for more info. Here is an example:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
   instances: 1
resources:
   cpu: 1
   memory_gb: 0.5
   disk_size_gb: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to verify it using the command top,  you need to connect to an instance in the console. Once there,  it's necessary know the running containers, use this command :

**"sudo docker ps"**

Once that you identified the container, run the following command

**sudo docker exec -it [CONTAINER-NAME] /bin/bash**

Then run the command top and you will see the available memory.

This is the documentation in case that you want to take a [look](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance)